# Given the following code what number will the message box display?

Tags: vb.net

I have below code and let me know what number will the message box display?

```
 for intCount = 1 to 5    
    bytTotal = bytTotal + 1*3    
 Next
 MsgBox intCount.
```

I am new to Vb.net and trying to solve this Problem.

Comment: Did you try running the code?

Comment: So go ahead and solve it.  SO is not a site for getting people to do your homework.  If you can't work out what should happen simply by reading the code then create a VB project and run it.  If you can tell us what you think should happen and why then we can tell you whether you're right or wrong but we're still not here to give you the right answer so that you don't have to try.

Comment: try the code before posting at SO

Comment: This is not even VB.NET. Seems more like VB6 to me.

Comment: It depends on how intCount is declared. If it is declared only in the `For` statement, you wont be able to run the code because intCount will be out of scope. However if intCount is declared outside the loop then you'll get 6. And yes. This isn't VB.Net code.

Answer (score 1):

Before exiting the For, intCount gets assigned the value 6, which is greater than 5, and therefore exits the loop.

The following code:

```
Dim intCount As Integer = 0
Dim bytTotal As Integer = 0

For intCount = 1 To 5

    bytTotal = bytTotal + 1 * 3

    Console.WriteLine("Inside for, intcount = " & intCount)

Next

Console.WriteLine("Outside for, intcount = " & intCount)
```

Will output:

```
Inside for, intcount = 1
Inside for, intcount = 2
Inside for, intcount = 3
Inside for, intcount = 4
Inside for, intcount = 5
Outside for, intcount = 6
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/tagt0z

So if you were to replace the second `Console.WriteLine` by `MessageBox.Show`, it would display 6.